# I want to jump from one page to another in HTML without using href tag. Is there any other tag or method I can use here?

Tags: html, tags, anchor

I have 2 xml files. In the first xml I want to give a link to another xml of the same project. Without using href tag how can I do this ?

1) `hold.xml`

2) `help.xml`

How can I call `help` in `Hold`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you use a button inside Hold. Create a function for button_click, in that function use DOM elements such as `document.getElementById("Button_1").href = "help.html";`. then you can call help in hold without href tag.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I also dont want to use button tAg here

Comment: at which event do you want to call the other web page?

Comment: I am looking something that will use onclick and jump

Answer (score 0):

This question is slightly confused. Are you using html or xml?

If you are using xml, investigate [XLink](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xlink.asp) but beware that there is no browser support for this.

If you are using html, just use an onclick attribute on any html element and use javascript to set location.href = 'url'

Comment: I am using html and I dont want to use JS and href tag

Comment: Create a form with an action=URL of the xml file. On form submit you will be redirected to the other file.